# is there a closed solution to counting pairwise combinations of the elements of two sets without resampling?

Tags: combinatorics, sampling

```
This is the pairing algorithm I have written and it seems to work.

numlist =(1,2,3,4)
letter_combinations=("pa","pb")
i=0
for num1 in numlist:
    for num2 in numlist:
        if num1 != num2:
            used_combinations = set()
            for comb1 in letter_combinations:
                for comb2 in letter_combinations:
                    if comb1 != comb2 and comb2 not in used_combinations:
                        print(f"({comb1}{num1},{comb2}{num2})", end=" ")
                        i += 1
                        used_combinations.add(comb1)
            print()
print(i)
```

The number of pairwise combinations without resampling is 12.

```
(pa1,pb2)
(pa1,pb3)
(pa1,pb4)
(pa2,pb1)
(pa2,pb3)
(pa2,pb4)
(pa3,pb1)
(pa3,pb2)
(pa3,pb4)
(pa4,pb1)
(pa4,pb2)
(pa4,pb3)
```

but is there a formula using the number of elements of each set to calculate the total number of pairs?

Comment: You have shown a specific example, but I cannot figure out how it generalizes. What do you mean by “using the number of elements of each set”? What are the sets? Please edit to describe your problem in its full generality.

Comment: I don't understand your use of the phrase "pairwise combinations of the elements of two sets without resampling".  However, reverse engineering your enumeration example, there are apparently 4 choices for the 1st component of the ordered pair.  Further, for each choice of the 1st component, there are apparently $~(4-1)~$ choices for the 2nd component of the ordered pair.

Comment: What if, instead of the two sets $~\{1,2,3,4\}~$ and $~\{1,2,3,4\},~$ you had the two sets $~\{1,2,3,4\}~$ and $~\{5,6,7,8\}~?$  What would the enumeration be then?

Comment: If $k$ is the size of `letter_combinations` and $n$ is the size of `numlist`, I think your code will print $\frac 12 n(n - 1) k(k - 1)$ different pairs of strings. (assuming they both consist of distinct elements, at least)

Comment: @MikeEarnest the two sets in the example above are the numlist and the lettercombination list. The number of elements in numlist is 4 and the number of elements in the letter combo list is 2. I am wondering how to derive a formula that uses these two parameters, 4 and 2, to calculate the number of outcomes of this process as defined above. (whose result in this example is 12). I kept the sets small for clarity. Clearly you can use N elements in the numlist and L elements in the letter list.

Comment: @user2661923 'without resampling' means the next member of the pair cannot cannot use any of the elements used by the first member. Since the numlist has 4 members and the letter list has 2, then after constructing the first member of the pair, you have 4-1 choices for the first element of the second member and 2-1 choices for the second element of the second member.

Comment: @user2661923 BTW, there are NOT two sets of {1,2,3,4} - there is ONE set of numbers and ONE set of letters. Or you can bring this example to reality and ask the question, in a room full of men and women, how many male-female couples can be arranged into a quartet to play bridge.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen sir, you have the intuition of a Schrodinger. Tell me how you came to this formula. But I imagine your derivation will be too long for a comment. It may be instructive to students of combinatorics tho and perhaps worthy of a blog entry if you have such a thing.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen also, make your comment an answer so I can mark it so. Perhaps in that answer you can illustrate your analysis.

Comment: You flatter me :). Mike's answer below is pretty much exactly how I arrived at that formula (after first looking at your code a bit to figure out what I thought it was doing exactly). The key idea is thinking about "once some parameters have been chosen, how many choices remain for the rest?", together with the observation that the choice of `(num1, num2)` is independent of the choice of `(comb1, comb2)`. These types of analyses become much easier with practice/experience (as with anything). Please do accept Mike's answer if you're happy with it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $N$ be the number of elements of `num_list`, and let $L$ be the number of elements of `letter_combinations`.

Every combination in this list looks like
$$
(n_1,\ell_1,n_2,\ell_2)
$$
such that...

- $n_1,n_2$ are in `num_list`, and $\ell_1,\ell_2$ are in `letter_combinations`.
- $n_1\neq n_2$, and $\ell_1\neq \ell_2$.
- $\ell_1$ appears earlier in `letter_combinations` than $\ell_2$.

Let us count the number of ways to specify such a list, using simple combinatorics.

- There are $N$ choices for $n_1$, since it can be anything in `num_list`.
- There are $N-1$ choices for $n_2$, since it can be anything in `num_list`, except for $n_1$.
- Choosing $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ requires a little more care. Naively, there are $L$ choices for $\ell_1$ (anything in `letter_combinations`), and there are $L-1$ choices for $\ell_2$ (anything in `letter_combinations` besides $\ell_1$). However, exactly half of these choices are invalid; for each $\ell_1\neq \ell_2$, only one of the pairs $(\ell_1,\ell_2)$ and $(\ell_2,\ell_1)$ is valid. Specifically, $(\ell_1,\ell_2)$ is valid if $\ell_1$ comes before $\ell_2$ in `letter_combinations_`, otherwise $(\ell_2,\ell_1)$ is the valid one.  
  Since there are $L\times (L-1)$ ways to choose the pair $(\ell_1,\ell_2)$, and exactly half of these are valid, the number of valid pairs is $L\times (L-1)/2$.

Putting this altogether, the number of combinations is
$$
N\times (N-1)\times L\times (L-1)/2.
$$